# Python - Function that reads content of a file and creates new file with contents in uppercase

Tags: python, formatting, filenames, uppercase, fasta

Apologies in advance if this has already been asked, but I have spent hours searching for answers on this. I'm a new student to Python (3.5.1, Windows 10) and my task is to write a function that reads the contents of a Fasta file (whose name is given by the user) and creates a new file (name also given by user, could be .fasta or .txt) with the Fasta sequences in uppercase. A fasta file is formatted so the title of a sequence is preceded by a caret and the subsequent lines are characters (those that I want to uppercase). A fasta file may have multiple >lines incorporated throughout the file, I do not want to uppercase these lines.

```
import sys
def fasta_upper(fasta_input_file, fasta_output_file):
    fasta_input_file = sys.argv
    with open('fasta_input_file', 'r') as f:
        file_contents = f.read()
        temp_contents = file_contents[:]
        for line in temp_contents:
            if line.startswith('>'):
                pass
            else:
                g = line.upper()
                open('fasta_output_file', 'w')
                fasta_output_file.write(g)
                fasta_input_file.close()
                fasta_output_file.close()
```

For example this Fasta File:

> Name of sequence
>   cgtatgggggtattccgtagctctgctgacgcgcttatatttagc
>   cgctcgatctggaggactctgcgatcgcggcatcgagctagcggc

Would be written like this:

> Name of sequence
>   CGTATGGGGGGTATTCCGTAGCTCTGCTGACGCGCTTATATTTAGC
>   CGCTCGATCTGGAGGACTCTCGATCGCGGCATCGAGCTAGCGCGGC

I'm sure this is just riddled with obvious mistakes, but again I'm am a student trying to learn. Please be gentle! Thank you in advance for any advice or tips you have, I have really enjoyed Python and I'd like to overcome this frustration and become a more affluent programmer :)

Answer (score 0):

A few corrections/improvements:

1) If you are opening the file with a "with" statement, you do not have to explicitly close it. With does this for you.

`fasta_input_file.close()` is therefore not neeeded.

2) For every line that does not begin with '>', this code is opening the 'fasta_output_file', overwriting the line and then closing it. Instead what you need to do is this.

initialise the variable outfile before the 'with' statement (So that you do not have to open and close inside the loop) `outfile = open('fasta_output_file', 'a')`

Write to the file in the else statement (`outfile.write(g)` should be in the else statement).

Close the output file after the 'with' statement exits. `outfile.close()`

A few more points:

You need to call the write() and close() methods on the file object that is created when you open the file.

Also, you are passing the filenames as the argument to the function and also trying to read from the command line arguments. You need to do only one of the two.

Answer (score 0):

1. You overwrite the passed `fasta_input_file` immediately with `sys.argv`. It's unclear whether the names should come from the caller or from arguments.
2. `sys.argv` is the sequence of arguments. You probably want the second one, `sys.argv[1]`.
3. You are confusing strings with names. `'fasta_input_file'` is not the same as `fasta_input_file`.
4. When you read a file with `read()`, it becomes a string. Iterating a string produces single characters rather than entire lines.
5. Rather than checking a condition and then doing `pass` if it's met, check for `not` that condition and then do whatever needs to be done in there.
6. `'fasta_output_file'` is, again, not the same as `fasta_output_file`.
7. You opened the output file but didn't save a reference (e.g. `out = open(...`) or create a context manager (e.g. `with open(...) as out:`).
8. You are closing the input and output files after a single "line."

Here is a sample of what your code might look like with these errors taken care of:

```
import sys

def fasta_upper():
    fasta_input_file, fasta_output_file = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
    with open(fasta_input_file) as f, open(fasta_output_file, 'w') as output:
        for line in f:
            if not line.startswith('>'):
                line = line.upper()
            output.write(line)

fasta_upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import re

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print('Usage:\n\t{} <input file> <output file>'.format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)

pattern = re.compile(r'\b[acgturykmswbdhvnx\-]+\b', re.M)

def repl(m):
    return m.group(0).upper()


with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as in_fh, open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as out_fh:
    for line in in_fh:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            out_fh.write(line)
        else:    
            out_fh.write(pattern.sub(repl, line))
```

Comment: @JoelCornett take a good look at examples. Ouwan12 want to convert only nucleotide sequences and left unchanged everything else, including sequences headers. Or have I missed an easier way?